# Match all punctuation not surrounded by alphanumeric characters?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re, punctuation

I am trying to write a regular expression that removes all non alphanumeric characters from a string, except for those that are surrounded by alphanumeric characters.

For example, consider the following three examples.

1.

`it's` -> `it's`

2.

`its.` -> `its`

3.

`It's a: beautiful day? I'm =sure it is. The coca-cola (is frozen right?`

`It's a beautiful day I'm sure it is The coca-cola is frozen right`

I am using Python's re module, and can match the opposite of what I am looking for with the following expression.

`(?<=[a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z ](?=[a-zA-Z])`

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `(?<![a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z\s]|[^a-zA-Z\s](?![a-zA-Z])`? See https://regex101.com/r/jNDVdD/1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
[^a-zA-Z\s](?!(?<=[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z])
```

[**Regex proof**](https://regex101.com/r/kYXpvY/1)

***EXPLANATION***

| PATTERN | DETAILS |
| --- | --- |
| `[^a-zA-Z\s]` | non-letter and non-whitespace |
| `(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z])` | unmatch if followed and preceded with letter |

Answer (score 3):

If alphanumeric characters can also be word characters like `\w` (including an underscore) you can use word boundaries:

```
[^a-zA-Z\s](?<!\b.\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `[^a-zA-Z\s]`
- `(?<!\b.\b)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a char to the left surrounded by word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NCnT5k/1)

Or another alternative using a case insensitive match excluding chars A-Z and digits on the left and right:

```
[^a-zA-Z\s](?<![A-Z\d].(?=[A-Z\d]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/izKZ4S/1)